# How to print memory address of a defined constant in C++

Tags: c++, constants, memory-address

Code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#define PI 3.14159

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    cout<<"Address of PI:"<<&PI<<endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

main.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:20: error: non-lvalue in unary`&'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[1]:**  [.build-conf] Error 2
make: ** [.build-impl] Error 2

So why can't I see the memory address of PI here?

Thank you.

Comment: `PI` won't have a memory address here.

Comment: A constant does not have a memory address.

Comment: If it does not have a memory address, where is the value stored?

Comment: @KorayTugay unspecified; usually in a register or in the instruction itself.

Comment: @Aardvark, the register is pretty expensive and easy to fill, isn't it? Would it be in the register?

Comment: A numeric constant is generally "stored" as an "immediate" value in the code.  That is, there are specific "load immediate value" instructions which include the constant value in the instruction itself.  And the same immediate value may be loaded 100 different places with 100 different instructions -- no single one is "the constant".  Even for longer literal (like strings) the value is stored in program space and you can't take its address.  Remember, we're talking about a *value* here, not a *place*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are never allocated a memory. Before the code is compiled, the compiler does a text search in the file and replace all Macros with their value. Also this is a text search, so the text gets replaced. So PI gets replaced by 3.14 in your code before compiling it. As a result, the memory operator throws an error because it cannot get the value of 3.14 as it is not a variable. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This means Anton Roth's comment is not correct. Right?

Comment: The macros are processed like text replace command, they dont mean anything in the compiling phase. So 3.14 is just a constant float in the program , not a variable. Also one more thing as it is a text search/replace then this preprocessor "#define PI x" would replace PI with x in the whole code, then &x would print the address of x if x is a variable at that point. "Preprocessor" means something thats done before the compiling process even starts ;)

Comment: When you have a const static double pi = 3.14; and never in your code call &pi, the compiler might or might not give it an address. If you call &pi at some point, it will be in memory at some point. For #define, it is as stated above, it is just replaced in text.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot take the address of a numeric literal. You could for a  variable, though:

```
// #define PI 3.14159
static const double PI = 3.14159;
```

Comment: Even like that it would only get an address once it is called somewhere in code. Otherwise the compiler will just replace it everywhere.

Comment: @AntonRoth: You have that backwards. It has an address, but the compiler may or may not, as an implementation detail, use the value of the variable directly in place of loading the variable's value, and additionally may remove the variable from existence altogether as a result.

Comment: @AntonRoth In the OP's given code (modified to use a `const double` as in this and other answers), where he explicitly takes the address of the constant, the constant would still be guaranteed to have an address no matter what optimizations the compiler does.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `PI` does not have a memory address. Since it's a preprocessor macro, its value gets substituted everywhere `PI` appears in your program.

If you turned it into a variable, you'd be able to take its address:

```
const double PI = 3.1415926;
```

Comment: Thanks. So it is more like a find / replace... I was thinking it like a variable.

Comment: Find/replace is a pretty good analogy. You can turn it into a variable, in which case you'll be able to take its address.

Comment: Does Aardvark's comment and this analogy make sense at the same time? If it is substituted everywhere in the code, is it needed to store the value in the register?

Comment: But note that, eg, an `enum` constant still doesn't have a location, even though, unlike the `#define` constant, it's not implemented via text substitution.

Comment: @KorayTugay Aardvark's comment does not address your question directly.  Whether the constant value ends-up optimized into a register (or immediate-style instruction) as-needed is neither here nor there for explaining the compiler's error message about you trying to evaluate the expression, after preprocessor substitution, of `&3.14`.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor will replace `PI` by `3.14159` everywhere in your code. Hence, the number does not reside in memory.

Comment: The statement "does not reside in memory" isn't very accurate - it may reside in memory, but in C++ there's no guarantees and no way to ask if/where it does.

Comment: Given the code in the question I don't see why the number would ever be in memory - the number isn't actually used. For more complicated code examples, I agree.